# Very weird Mysql Error on SQL UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called notifier with 11 columns :

```
CREATE TABLE `notifier` (
  `NUM_UTILISATEUR` int(32) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `NUM_NOTIFICATION` int(32) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `LU` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `DATE_NOTIFIER` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `NUM_PENSEE` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `NUM_CONTRIBUTION` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `NUM_COMMENTAIRE` int(32) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `CODE_NOTIF` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VU` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `DATE_VU` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `DATE_LU` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And I want to update only the 2 columns : VU and DATE_LU. 
For that, I ran this mysql query :

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @TheGameiswar Better yet, what is the query?

Comment: My wild guess: you need to look into ALTER TABLE.

Comment: I want to post the query, but I get this SO error : "An error occurred during comment submission"

Comment: And I want to update only the 2 columns : VU and DATE_LU. For that, I ran this mysql query in phpmyadmin :

Comment: "UpDATE notifier SET VU=1, DATE_LU = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') WHERE NUM_UTILISATEUR=130 AND NUM_PENSEE = 113 AND CODE_NOTIF=2 AND NUM_CONTRIBUTION=439 AND NUM_COMMENTAIRE=600" But It updates 3 columns : VU, DATE_VU and DATE_LU, instead of 2 (VU, DATE_LU) ! Any idea what is going on ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow  works now

Comment: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` makes no sense

Comment: Really ? Why it adds a date and time when I use it ? So what should I suppose to use ?

Comment: [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) does not work like that; doing a SELECT of that expression returns null. You are using MySQL (as your tags, and engine, indicate), right?

Comment: Yeah thanks! What should I do ? I replaced my date(...) by NOW() but my issue remains !